# critical section in a clustered environment

Tags: critical-section

This may sound really silly but i need to clear my doubt. I am making this bus ticket booking system just like RedBus as a part of my project.I was just wondering how it would work in a clustered environment. As in if i had just 1 ticket and i get 2 requests at the same time how do i deal with that in a cluster as i will have multiple servers. Also should i maintain the critical section in each server or somewhere common to all the servers . I tried googling but i am,not satisfied with the answers i get. I thought of locking the critical section but how is that possible in a cluster?

Comment: I did this once and used a SQL database for a master lock file.

Comment: could you be a little more specific.?Accessing the database everytime will consume a lot of time right.? how did you use the db?

Comment: As a practical matter it will not consume a lot of time: consider how many php applications work. The trick is to minimize the accesses to such a database. In many databases only the very very last step (the purchase) will actually lock the ticket: usually while credit card processing begins. The credit card processing phase is expected to take a certain amount of time and if it fails the ticket must unlock.

Comment: but dont you think the problem of race condition will still persist because 2 requests can still come at the sametime and hence  acesss to the db lock will be simultaneous.....how to treat 2 requests coming at the sametime?

Answer (score 1):

Critical section part alone can be moved into common system where all clusters will send request to that system for allocating a seat.

This is the only answer, I can think.